# wcf server authentication without certificates

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I have a self-hosted WCF service with netTcpBinding bindings.  Both my servers and clients will all be in the same domain, so I'd like to use windows authentication, but I'd also like the clients to verify server credentials (to avoid an internal man-in-the-middle/dns tampering attack).  I've read that the way to do this is to use an SPN, but I can't seem to get that to work; no matter what the spn is set to the client works (i.e. the server and client don't match, but the client connects anyway).  Obviously I've got some kind of configuration error, but I'm not sure where.  Here is the service config for the server:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="AaaAuthService.AaaAuthService" behaviorConfiguration="AaaAuthServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IAaaAuth" contract="AAA.IAaaAuthService">
      <!--
      <identity>            
        <servicePrincipalName value="AaaShlkjhlkjjjjhhhhjjpn/justink-pc.sgasdf1.allamericanasphaltasdf.casdfom"/>
      </identity>
      -->
    </endpoint>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9000/IAaaAuthService"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="AaaAuthServiceBehavior">
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="2147483647" maxConcurrentInstances="2147483647" maxConcurrentSessions="2147483647"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IAaaAuth" closeTimeout="00:00:20" openTimeout="00:00:10" receiveTimeout="00:00:10" sendTimeout="00:00:10" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxConnections="2147483647">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign"/>
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

The windows credentials do seem to get passed in - OperationContext.Current.ServerSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity is populated with the account information.

What am I missing here?

Comment: In a domain you can secure DNS.  Still good practice to validate both ends.  Valid question.

Comment: Something strange here - if I use a DnsIdentity with a bogus name it fails as expected, but if I use an SpnIdentity with a bogus name it works like a charm.  Seems that it is ignoring the SpnIdentity for some reason.

Comment: `            System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress epa = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(new Uri(strUri), EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("asdfasdfasdfasdf"), addressHeader);

            NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();

            binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
            binding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;
            binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.Windows;`